Is it no longer possible to install certificates on FireTV?
After a couple of months I had to update my Charles certificate on my Amazon Fire TV (3rd gen, Fire OS 6.7.0.5) device to be able to proxy SSL traffic again.
The steps were taken from
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/network-proxy.html
and have worked well so far.
But now during the saving process of the certificate no Amazon credentials form appears and so every try to save fails.
I am able to set a name for the certificate but then there is no authentication possible.
What am I missing?
I used this procedure successfully at the beginning of the year.

I have the same error on fOS 6.7.0.5, it was working on 6.7.0.3.
I simply bought a new device with fOS 7 and following the same flow was able to install a cert on new device

Ok, thank you, good to know but I have to test it on 6.x.
